# Tuning the Logit model based on sensitivity

Tags: logistic, classification, predictive-models, sas, sensitivity-specificity

I am working on a logistic model to predict whether or not an employee is likely to take a leave day during a given three month period. The model only correctly classified the “non-event"
observations(as per the SaS classification table). The requirement says "Is there a way to tune the model so that at most 20% of the people who don't use the leave policy(non-events) are incorrectly predicted by the model to use the leave policy(events)?If the model can be tuned that way, how good will the model be at accurately identifying people who actually will use the leave policy in three months if we do that?"
I am not sure 20% should be the prob. cutoff or I need to look for 20% incorrect "events" threshold in the classification table and that's should be considered classification rate of my model. Any guidance would be appreciated.

The data has 1030 observations out of which 206 are events(took leave) and 824 are non events(took no leave).